# Linking problems for BLAS, Lapack, Gomp libraries (64bit)

Tags: c++, lapack, blas, pardiso

I have been trying to compile my C++-program with the following command:

```
g++ -g -O0 -fopenmp -L/home/donkokse/development/workspace -o "NS_Solver" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

with

```
LIBS := -lgomp /usr/lib/liblapack.so /usr/lib/libblas.so /home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so
```

under Ubuntu 13.04, 64bit. The problem is that I still keep getting the following error messages:

```
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_concat_string'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dtrmm_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `lsame_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dlartg_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dswap_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dgemm_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dger_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_dynamic_next'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_single_start'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dgels_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dlartv_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zscal_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zlaev2_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `sswap_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_end'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `izamax_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zgetrf_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dsteqr_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `slaswp_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dtrsv_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dsyr_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zsyr_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zgeru_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `sscal_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dlaswp_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zgemm_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dgeev_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_atomic_end'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dscal_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zdscal_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `ilaenv_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zgemv_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `isamax_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zlacgv_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dsyevr_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zpotf2_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `sgemm_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dsyr2k_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `ssyr_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dsytri_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `sgetrf_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_critical_name_start'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dtrsm_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dlascl_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `idamax_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dpotrf_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dorgtr_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_end_nowait'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_end'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dsytd2_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_critical_start'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dsytrf_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zher_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dggev_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_wtime_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zrot_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_critical_name_end'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_exit_i4'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dlatrd_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_critical_end'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dlapy2_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zlaswp_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_atomic_start'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `zswap_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `xerbla_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dormqr_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_barrier'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dgeqrf_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dgemv_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `sgemv_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dsterf_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_start'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dlamch_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `ztrsm_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `sger_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `strsm_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_os_error'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dgetrs_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_dynamic_start'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dgetri_'
/home/harry/development/libpardiso412-GNU443-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `dlansy_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [NS_Solver] Error 1
```

It seems to find the libraries. I tried out different things like reinstalling the libraries, changing the order of the libraries, checking if I really have 64bit versions of them by

```
objdump -a /usr/lib/libblas.so
```

and also the suggestions at "Recursive references of libraries" on the page
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-portfortan.html#ur, although the grouping didn't work for g++.
What else could be wrong? I also tried compiling an optimized version of openMP for a Theano installation (different project though). Could it be that this messes up my openMP somehow? How can I test that? I would like to remove that optimized version again and install the one from the synaptic package manager. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using `extern "C"` where it is needed?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I have some parts in the code, especially the ones that use functions from the pardiso library, which are pure C - I could use extern C for them.
On the other hand, I am not sure if need extern "C" though - compilation of this project worked on a two year old openSuse installation on VMWare, before I decided to install Ubuntu on my harddrive. The openSuse installation was 32bit, Ubuntu is 64bit. Could there be problems because of the change in architecture? Could there also be  problems/changes because of newer compiler/library versions?